# Basic shipping rates help

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

Hi I just wondered how it was easiest to provide these basic shipping rates:

Royal Mail using 2nd class signed for:

- £5 on orders below £50 (being total value in basket)
- £10 on orders below £175
- Free over £175
- Courier option £15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Table Rate Shipping method.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Free shipping over $175 can be done with Free Shipping back end configuration

Comment: This doesn't account for the Courier option that he needs.  For that also use the Flat Rate Shipping Method and rename the label to Courier.

Comment: agree....i missed that part